# Is it possible in Java to turn an object fully into its base type?

Tags: java

If I have two related classes `A` and `B` such `class B extends A` and then create a instance of `B`, is there any way to fully upcast it such that it is now, effectively, an instance of `A`?

```
B b = new B();
A a = full_upcast_to_A(b);
a.class.equals(A.class)
```

It's this last line that is important.  I don't want a reference to a `B` object through an `A` variable.  It want the referenced `A` object to look and behave just as if it has been created with `new A()`.

If I do a standard `A a = (A) b;`, the object is still, internally, of type `B` should you look at `.class` or call any overridden methods.  I don't want that.

A *copy* of base class `A` into a new `A` object is acceptable but not preferred.

**Update: The Why Of It:**

It's a complicated situation.  I have a POJO data class (`A`) that is common code but I can't load that from datastore because those need an @Entity annotation so I have a derived class (`B`) that adds nothing but that annotation and thus allows storage.  However, I need to pass an `A` back through a GWT RPC because the client doesn't know about `B`.  GWT refuses to do such because it only knows how to serialize `A` and its receiving a `B`.

*`B` was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.*

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: noooooo.  Copying is the only alternative.

Comment: This would completely break what overriding methods does, and could leave the object in an inconsistent state through no fault of its own. E.g. ```toString()``` *always* calls the most "recent" implementation in the class hierarchy.

Comment: Nope, and the need to do so, even creating a new A from B, indicates a design flaw. B is an A, by definition, means A is not a B. A bit more info might lead to a better solution. Why being the main question.

Comment: I've updated the question with the why of it.  I understand the risks posed by this but am not worried about them in my use case.  I didn't really expect it to be possible, but thought I'd check just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is not directly possible, I think.

The way I would accomplish the same is to use the copy constructor pattern, like so:

```
public class A {
    public A(A copy) {
        // Copy the relevant state into new A instance here.
    }
}
```

You would then use as such:

```
B b = new B();
A a = new A(b);
```

Edit:

Tony Hopkinson is right though, I'm not really sure why you would want to do this.

Comment: A can just have `public A(A copy) {...}`.  It doesn't need to know anything about B.  I also think I could just implement `clone()` on `A` but since I want `A` to be just fields and no methods (or at least no complicated methods, and `clone()` is complicated), I'm avoiding it.

Comment: You are right of course. I've updated my answer to reflect that. I have some experience with GWT and JPA and I am curious as to why it will refuse to serialize B. If the only change is an added annotation I cannot see why it wouldn't work. I've had @Entity annotated classes be serializable by GWT before. Can you give us more details on the reason or error that you're having from trying to use B in GWT RPC?

Comment: Is a copy-ctor better than a static `copy(A a)` method that does `new` and then copies fields?  I believe GWT just looks at the `.class` to validate it against the types it knows, possibly so that you don't accidentally send too much.  I'll add the error message to the question.

Comment: Both would work fine. In this case I would be inclined to go the route of a constructor because a constructor is being invoked regardless - it's just that with a copy method you're calling a default constructor and then copying fields as opposed to just calling an actual copy constructor directly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I understand the root issue here. I'm not sure what JPA provider you are using but I had this same issue with Hibernate and it is possibly the same as you're experiencing now.

GWT is a clever framework. As long as what you're trying to serialize implements serializable and all of its members are also serializable, it should be able to send the object to the client side. What some JPA providers do when you access a database, is they provide some clever caching that only loads the data and members that are specifically requested. Hibernate, for example, does this by providing an object that isn't exactly the one you get when you call `new B()`. It will give you an object that has the interface of B but behind the scenes it is using proxies to fetch data from the database when getter methods are called. It will replace standard java lists with classes like `PersistentBag` that will also use proxies to the database when you access them.

When you try to send this proxified object to the client, GWT looks at all these unserializable proxies and rejects them, as it should. The client wouldn't be able to access the database directly regardless. You can test if this is what is happening by looking at the code in a debugger and seeing what the properties of an object is during runtime. In any case, the way I solved it is by using Dozer, a library designed to take one form of class and map it into another. You can also use copy constructors. You don't even need to convert your B into an A. You could use `new B(b)` and as long as all the fields you want are copied over, the database accesses have already happened and you have an instance of B that GWT can understand.

For more information on this, see the [GWT Project Homepage: Hibernate](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html). In particular the section on "Why Hibernate objects can't be understood when they reach the browser world".